# Split string based on the first occurrence of the character

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

How can I split a C# string based on the first occurrence of the specified character?
Suppose I have a string with value:

```
101,a,b,c,d
```

I want to split it as

```
101
```

```
a,b,c,d
```

That is by the first occurrence of comma character.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can specify how many substrings to return using [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char()-system-int32)):

```
var pieces = myString.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2);
```

Returns:

```
101
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 26):

```
string s = "101,a,b,c,d";
int index = s.IndexOf(',');
string first =  s.Substring(0, index);
string second = s.Substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: @pcnThird I didn't downvote but is probably because it is just code with no explanation of the method being used.

Comment: @pcnThird, Don't know, though I think GrantWinney's answer is the best.

Comment: Actually, this one provides a fine alternative to the GrantWinney's answer for those not having access to this split method. (Those using the compact framework for exemple)

Comment: Maybe because if IndexOf can't find the delimiter it returns -1.  In this case,  the code will not correctly split the string.  It should return the entire string as first, but first will be empty (or possibly crash).

Answer (score 15):

You can use `Substring` to get both parts separately.

First, you use `IndexOf` to get the position of the first comma, then you split it :

```
string input = "101,a,b,c,d";
int firstCommaIndex = input.IndexOf(',');

string firstPart = input.Substring(0, firstCommaIndex); //101
string secondPart = input.Substring(firstCommaIndex + 1); //a,b,c,d
```

On the second part, the `+1` is to avoid including the comma.

Comment: Don't use this; firstCommaIndex can be -1 if the comma was never found.

Comment: `string firstPart = firstCommaIndex == -1 ? "" : input.Substring(0, firstCommaIndex);` works fine. Great answer if you have more advanced things to do

Answer (score 9):

Use `string.Split()` function. It takes the max. number of chunks it will create. Say you have a string "abc,def,ghi" and you call Split() on it with `count` parameter set to 2, it will create two chunks "abc" and "def,ghi". Make sure you call it like `string.Split(new[] {','}, 2)`, so the C# doesn't confuse it with the other overload.

Comment: but see @sierra 's answer below

Answer (score 3):

```
var pieces = myString.Split(',', 2);
```

This won't work. The overload will not match and the compiler will reject it.

So it Must be:

```
char[] chDelimiter = {','};
var pieces = myString.Split(chDelimiter, 2);
```

Comment: or `var pieces = myString.Split([','], 2);`

Answer (score 1):

In .net Core you can use the following;

```
var pieces = myString.Split(',', 2);
```

Returns:

```
101
a,b,c,d
```

Comment: `Split(',', 2)` triggers a warning, with Visual Studio asking to cast `2` to `char`.