# Spliting a string in c# by : but ignoring :: and any brackets

Tags: c#, regex, split, brackets

*I'm using c# with .net core 3.0*
I have the following strings

1. pose: [x: -0.940038204, y: -0.00377289206, theta: -0.0824421719]
2. state: PoseLocalisationState_T::NOT_LOCALIZED

I want to split it so I get the following.

1. pose  ,  [x: -0.940038204, y: -0.00377289206, theta: -0.0824421719]
2. state ,  PoseLocalisationState_T::NOT_LOCALIZE

I am currently using

`string[] couple = Regex.Split(token_trimmed, ":(?!([^{]*}|[^[]*]))");`

This works to get line 1, however when I try it with line 2 I get:

```
state , PoseLocalisationState_T, ,NOT_LOCALIZED
```

How can I get Regex to ignore '::'? I think I need to use (?<!) or maybe the look ahead equivalent, but I have no idea what to move forward with this.

Comment: Are you not simply trying to split at the first `:` each time?

Comment: Maybe all you need is split with the first `:` occurrence? `var pieces = myString.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21519598/3832970